# Last value is printed instead of all values using list.each in groovy

Tags: list, groovy, each

Please help me to correct error. Please help to understand the error and guide me to resolve.

Asset name:
Laptop 
Asset number:
1
Asset model:
Pavilion Notebook
Assigned date:
28/08/2017 
Price:
62000
Do you want to continue?(Yes/No)
Yes

Asset name:
Speakers
Asset number:
2
Asset model:
5.1
Assigned date:
12/07/2017
Price:
12000
Do you want to continue?(Yes/No)
No

Asset.No : 1 | Name : Laptop | Model : Pavilion Notebook | Last Assigned Date : 28-08-2017 | Price : 62000.0

Asset.No : 2 | Name : Speakers | Model : 5.1 | Last Assigned Date : 12-07-2017 | Price : 12000.0

```
class Main
{
    static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Asset asset = new Asset()
        List list = new ArrayList()
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
        String userInput = "Yes"
        while(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
        {
            println "Asset name:"
            asset.name  = br.readLine()
            println "Asset number:"
            asset.assetNumber  = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())
            println "Asset model:"
            asset.model  = br.readLine()
            println "Assigned date:"
            asset.lastAssignedDate  = Date.parse("dd/MM/yyyy", br.readLine())
            println "Price:"
            asset.price = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine())
            list.add(asset)
            println "Do you want to continue?(Yes/No)"
            userInput = br.readLine()
        }
        list.each
        {
            println it
        }
    }
}

class Asset
{
    def name
    def assetNumber
    def model
    def lastAssignedDate
    def price

    String toString()
    {
        sprintf "Asset.No : "+assetNumber+" | Name : "+name+"| Model : "+model+" | Last Assigned Date : "+lastAssignedDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy")+" | Price : "+price.round(2)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error description is missleading.  You store your values in the same `asset` and add that again and again in your list.  So your list contains "input times" the last asset.  Move the `def asset = new Asset()` into your loop to fix that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help.