# Print the specific field from list

Tags: groovy

Please help to print the assetNumber. Need to search for specific assetname and print its associated assetNumber using list in groovy.

Currently, it does not print value. It struck once search criteria is entered.

```
class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
List list = new ArrayList()
Asset asset = new Asset()
def name
def assetNumber
def assigneeName
def assignedDate
def assetType
String userInput = "Yes"
while(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
{
println "Enter the asset details:"
asset.name = br.readLine()
asset.assetNumber= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())
asset.assigneeName = br.readLine()
asset.assignedDate = Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', br.readLine())
list.add(asset)
println "Do you want to continue(yes/no)"
userInput = br.readLine()
}
println "Enter the asset type:"
assetType = br.readLine()
println "Asserts with type "+assetType+":"
def items = list.findAll{p->p.name == assetType }
items.each { println it.assetNumber }
}
}
 class Asset
{
def name
def assetNumber
def assigneeName
def assignedDate
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last value is printed instead of all values using list.each in groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121976/last-value-is-printed-instead-of-all-values-using-list-each-in-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value in your Asset object, then adding the same object to the list every time

If you create a new asset inside the loop (rather than outside it), it should work...

Something like this:

```
import groovy.transform.*

class Main {
    static main(args) {
        def console = System.console()
        def list = []
        while (true) {
            def name = console.readLine 'Enter the asset name:'
            def number = console.readLine 'Enter the asset number:'
            def assignee = console.readLine 'Assignee name:'
            def date = console.readLine 'Date (dd/MM/yyyy):'
            list << new Asset(
                name: name,
                assetNumber: Integer.parseInt(number),
                assigneeName: assignee,
                assignedDate: Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', date)
            )
            if ('Y' != console.readLine('Enter another (y/n):')?.take(1)?.toUpperCase()) {
                break
            }
        }
        def type = console.readLine 'Enter the asset type:'
        println "Assets with type $type:"
        list.findAll { p -> p.name == type }
            .each { println it.assetNumber }
    }

    @Canonical
    static class Asset {
        def name
        def assetNumber
        def assigneeName
        def assignedDate
    }
}
```